# Проблема с обьединением двух sql запросов

Tags: sql

Есть два запроса, первый выводит все продукты из таблицы `products`:

```
CREATE TABLE products(
    product_id                          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    ....
    likes                               INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Сам запрос:

`SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS`.

Второй считает лайки из таблицы `likes`:

```
CREATE TABLE likes(
    like_id                             SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    product_id                          INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    user_id                             INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Сам запрос:

```
`SELECT COUNT(1) FROM LIKES WHERE PRODUCT_ID = '${product_id}'.
```

Мне надо чтобы в таблице `products` в поле `likes`, было количество лайков из таблицы `likes`. Вопрос, как почситать лайки по `product_id` в таблице `likes` и записать это в таблицу `products` в поле `likes`?

Comment: Посчитать - обычным группирующим запросом, связав таблицы. Записать в таблицу - а нафига, если оно элементарно считается? чтобы получить рассогласование при первом же сбое? `SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` - не забудьте дропнуть лишний индекс.

Comment: Есть хотя бы пример? Я в упор не вижу решения этого

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*, COUNT(l.product_id) likes
FROM products p, likes l
WHERE p.product_id = l.product_id
GROUP BY p.product_id /* , fieldset */
```

И обратите внимание на несоответствие типов - `products.product_id` имеет тип `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL`, тогда как `likes.product_id` имеет тип `INTEGER SIGNED NOT NULL`. Это - возможный источник проблемы.